# Pi NoIR Vs Regular camera for face detection

Tags: pi-2, raspicam

i am using a raspberry oi v2 and i'm looking t work with a raspberry pi camera module ,

so they are two types : the

**regular camera** : used in day light and for photography

**the pi NoIR camera** : used in minimum light conditions or indoor ..

For face detection i'm wondering what camera can be chosen for best performance and accuracy ? without taking into account indoor or outdoor application

NB:  i'm using viola jones method for deetcting faces and one of it's advantages is the Sensitivity to lighting conditions !!!
thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

The NoIR board does not have an IR (infrared) filter on board. What this means is that for low light application if you are to use IR leds to light up the place, the NoIR camera will work best and the regular board will block out the IR resulting in a dark image.

So all in all it depends on whether or not you need night vision. Everything else is the same.

Have a look at [this blog](http://pimylifeup.com/raspberry-pi-camera-vs-noir-camera/) he clearly shows the difference between the two cameras

Hope it helps

Comment: The face detection depends on illumination it could be some differences ... maybe , plz have you a link that show they are the same for face detection , thanks

Comment: The sensors on both boards are the same. You can have a look at the products page of the two  boards

Comment: Have a look at the technical details of https://www.adafruit.com/products/1567 and https://www.adafruit.com/products/1367

Comment: yes i have view those pages but they don't provide useful informations about my issue

Comment: What I wanted to show you is that the on board sensor is the same. What other information do you require?

Comment: si the two cameras are just different by IR filter , i want to know if the illumination will affect the face detection because i'm using viola jones method for deetcting faces and one og it's advantage is the Sensitivity to lighting conditions

Comment: I have updated my answer